# PowerShell arguments beginning with / are replaced with "True"

Tags: powershell

As the title says, any argument passed to a PowerShell script that starts with a '/' is replaced with True.

For a script

```
param (
    [string]$wd = ""
)
echo $wd
```

And run with `.\script.ps1 -wd "/etc/xyz"`, the output is `True` instead of the expected `/etc/xyz`. I was unable to find this behavior documented elsewhere, except for a similar issue in vbscript.

How can I get the string as-is?

Comment: Can't reproduce. What is you Powershell version? check "$PSVersionTable.PSVersion"

Comment: My PS version is 5.1.15063.632. I think it may have something to do with what PS2EXE did. I'll take a look at that.

Comment: You have a new version of Powrshell so I guess it has nothing to do with PS. Update us with further information :)

Comment: Try to retype your command line (and function), excluding known copy-paste issues as with [non-standard dash characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43776009/powershell-script-error-the-string-is-missing-the-terminator/43776630). If it still doesn't work put the whole function in your question as with the current information the issue can't be reproduced.